# How can I subdivide this surface or what do I need to do to the surface to make it able to subdivide

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am building a tunnle. I used torus meshes to build the roof and sides and then just added a face to the bottom. [image]

problem is that I want to subdivide it and can't seem to. When I try to just hit subdivide nothing happens. Then I tried applying sub-surface mod and the mesh deformed.
[image]

What can I do to the mesh to divide it up??

Comment: Please show your mesh in [edit] mode. If you have more than one, show the one that has the most problems.

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation

Probably that face used for the ground is an n-gon. It isn't possible to subdivide an n-gon directly to produce predictable results, all it does is add vertices to the perimeter.

[image]

On the left is a similar structure that has edges spanning to each opposite vertex. On the right the face was generated in one go by selecting all perimeter edges and pressing F to generate one face (an n-gon)

[image]

and that's OK until you try to apply a modifier like Subsurf, because you don't have any control over the way Blender internally constructs the n-gon geometry.

[image]

#### Solution

Judging by the geometry I see in your image, it might be possible to select the n-gon, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get the faces menu and select option 'Triangulate Faces', this will make initial cuts. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> again and select 'Tris to Quads`. This might produce the following geometry.

[image]

#### Realistically.

Once you get a bit more practice with Blender you'll probably approach making a tunnel in a different way.

An efficient way to make a tube/tunnel is to create a profile shape and then use that as a bevel object for a curve.

[image]